# iOS stacktrace error line number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack-trace

I have an application already in AppStore, and i override this method:

```
 void onUncaughtException(NSException* exception){
[H trackUserWithExceptionDescription:exception.description AndDetails:[exception.callStackSymbols description]];
 }
```

And as you see i'm sending all the errors to my server's database.

Now, i have the table with exception description and stacksymbol.

The question is how can i determine the line of code which the error happens ?

This is a sample of my database row

exception name:

```
*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

and stacktrace:

```
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x261bb14f <redacted> + 150
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x34592c77 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x260cd217 <redacted> + 178
3   TickerChart                         0x000edd01 TickerChart + 105729
4   TickerChart                         0x000ed635 TickerChart + 103989
5   TickerChart                         0x0011384d TickerChart + 260173
6   TickerChart                         0x001135c9 TickerChart + 259529
7   TickerChart                         0x000f90d5 TickerChart + 151765
8   Foundation                          0x26efa235 __NSFireTimer + 64
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2618115f <redacted> + 14
10  CoreFoundation                      0x26180ce1 <redacted> + 656
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2617ef4b <redacted> + 1418
12  CoreFoundation                      0x260ca9a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
13  CoreFoundation                      0x260ca7b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
14  GraphicsServices                    0x2d85a1a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
15  UIKit                               0x29855695 UIApplicationMain + 1440
16  TickerChart                         0x000fb8ab TickerChart + 161963
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x34b3aaaf <redacted> + 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into the tab that looks like a line break on the left pain in Xcode. Go to the bottom left and click the plus. Then click add exception breakpoint. Then under exception choose language. Make sure its enabled by clicking the line break icon

Comment: okay, i already done that.
but i'm not asking for debugging the Application in Xcode !
i have these errors on my database in the server and i need to know where it happens exactly.

Comment: Oh, I have no idea then, sorry :)